# React Redux returning list of props [Metronic Theme]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a question regarding React-Redux returning a list of redux-specific props when I initialise the page.
If I console.log the this.props.address (the content I'm fetching) I'll get back a list of `(4) [true, null, false, {…}]` (with the last item eventually being what I need).

For this reason, I have problems accessing the content of the actual Axios request (even though it's always the very last item of the list). Only if I do `{this.props.address.slice(-1)[0].href}` can I access an item of the returned JSON. I guess this is not how it's supposed to be, so I must be doing something wrong.

I'm quite new to React, and I'm therefore not that familiar of the different ways of using Redux. However, I have cut it down to something going on in the initial state when I'm using the createSlice from `reduxjs/toolkit` (something I haven't used before, but it is currently used by the theme I'm working with, so I'm trying to copy the ways they've set it up).

I have attached the code below, and would appreciate any input leading me in the right direction.
I have a lot more files than these - but I'm quite sure these three files would handle the problem.

**Research.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchAddress } from "./_redux/addressActions";

class Research extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchAddress(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.address);

    return <h1>{this.props.address.slice(-1)[0].href}</h1>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    address: Object.values(state.address),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchAddress })(Research);
```

**addressSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialAddressState = {
  initialState: true,
};

export const callTypes = {
  list: "list",
  action: "action",
};

export const addressSlice = createSlice({
  name: "addresses",
  initialState: initialAddressState,
  reducers: {
    addressFetched: (state, action) => {
      state.actionsLoading = false;
      state.address = action.payload.address;
      state.error = null;
    },
  },
});
```

**addressAction.js**

```
import * as requestFromServer from "./addressCrud";
import { addressSlice, callTypes } from "./addressSlice";

const { actions } = addressSlice;

export const fetchAddress = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  if (!id) {
    return dispatch(actions.addressFetched({ address: undefined }));
  }

  dispatch(actions.startCall({ callType: callTypes.action }));
  return requestFromServer
    .getAddress(id)
    .then((response) => {
      const address = response.data;
      dispatch(actions.addressFetched({ address: address }));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      error.clientMessage = "Can't find address";
      dispatch(actions.catchError({ error, callType: callTypes.action }));
    });
};
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `this.props.address[this.props.address.length - 1].href` work?

Comment: It does work!! Thanks. What are you thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, I figured out that eventually my changes to the other files did not necessarily cause the correction, but instead your suggestion about rendering the content first in a separate function. My struggle however was that I set the initial state to true, and didn't evaluate for this. I have no changed the initial state på `null` and I evaluate if (!this.props.address) { return null } else {return something}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited Answer: Based on the comment below there does seem to be some built in loading state management with `actionsLoading` and `actions.startCall`.

Should be able to use `this.props.actionsLoading` to avoid rendering, and also setup good default values **always**.

Edited Answer: Getting more clarity.

I can't find any record redux toolkit handling the loading state for your application. What if you setup that loading state yourself similar to how they have it on their documentation https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#asynchronous-logic-and-data-fetching.

Would need to handle the loading in the reducer.

```
export const addressSlice = createSlice({
  name: "addresses",
  initialState: initialAddressState,
  reducers: {
    addressLoading: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    addressFetched: (state, action) => {
      if(state.loading) {
        state.loading = false;
        state.address = action.payload.address;
        state.error = null;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Then make sure to dispatch the event to indicate loading has started.

```
dispatch(actions.addressLoading());
  return requestFromServer
    .getAddress(id)
    .then((response) => {
      const address = response.data;
      dispatch(actions.addressFetched({ address: address }));
    })
```

I would also always include reasonable defaults in my initial state.

```
const initialAddressState = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  address: null
};
```

The last step is avoiding the render if we are loading or don't have data. Also a lot of ways to do this. It's hard to know what your best options are without seeing the rest of the application.

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props.address);
  if(this.props.loading || this.props.address === null) return null;
  return <h1>{this.props.address.href}</h1>;
}
```

Hoping that is closer to the issue.

Edited Answer: I originally misunderstood the question.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    address: Object.values(state.address),
  };
};
```

This will create an array of values out of the state.address object. So in this case an object that looks like this:

```
const obj = { first: true, second: false };
const oops = Object.values(obj);

console.log(oops); // [true, false]
```

I'm not sure entirely how you want your data to show up, but if you want the address object, then assign it with `address: state.address`.

Original Answer: Normally in JavaScript we access the last item of an array like this. You can shorten it by making a local variable that points to address.

```
const address = this.props.address;
address[address.length - 1];
```

In your example you are taking the last element of the array (slice lets you go from the end back to the middle with negative numbers) and slicing that into its own array. After that you access it as the first element of that new array with [0].

I think based on the description of what you want, doing the last item access is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. However, the part I'm confused about is more why I get an array of 4 items when I should only get 1 item back in total - so I would prefer to have a method where I could access it directly without slicing it.

Comment: Oh I see. My mistake. Well it looks like the API returns an array. So you have to slice it at some point. 

`dispatch(actions.addressFetched({ address: address }));`

This is where it comes from the server and is set to the redux state. Address is an array here, so you could move that logic here.

`dispatch(actions.addressFetched({ address: address[address.length - 1] }));`

The only way to avoid this is to make a request to the backend for a single address, instead of a list.

Comment: Hi there, I don't really think it has anything to do with the API as this does not return an array. Also, when I console.log it, it see that it is fetched 4 times in total, with one element added to the this.props.address each time. So it's something that happens after it has fetched the content.

Comment: Again, apologies. I think I got it this time :)

Comment: Hi Jens, many thanks for your inputs! The only thing I want is to access the .address property directly - I don't need the first three values of the array, as these are not necessary. I think the reason the get generated is becaused of the initial values in the addressSlice.js file (where initialState: true) which is why index 0 and 2 of the arrays turns out to be true. But I just want to skip this initial stage.

Comment: The reason you have props.address as an array is because you call Object.values(state.address) in the mapStateToProps function. Object.values returns an array of values from an object.

Comment: I think that is a good point, however, I get the following error when I remove it: TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined.
It does look correct though with this change, however, when I output it e.g. in an h1 tag it does not show anything (though it show it correctly in the console.log what I want - it renders a total of 4 times, corresponding to the 4 items in the array).
So I think this stems back to the initial value from the addressSlice.js that I can't figure out.

Comment: Are you saying that with

`class Research extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.address);

    return <h1>{this.props.address.href}</h1>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    address: state.address,
  };
};`
this.props.address is undefined? What value is output by the console.log. Sorry about formatting.

Comment: Like this I do not get the undefined error, however the output never makes it do the browser (not even after everything seems to be loaded correctly, so it's not because of a delay). Interestingly, if I try to access a child of it, I get the undefined error. I think the reason is that it initially never contains that, as it only does so in the 4th render, and when trying to access it on the 1-3rd rendering, it's undefined.

Comment: So that console.log never gets called? I'm confused about that. When Research renders it would be nice to know the props.address value all 4 times. If this is the case, then you really just need to setup loading state and avoid rendering the address until your loading is complete. The other option is to set it up with defaults that prevent it from crashing.

Comment: Yes, it does make it to the console. 
1) {initialState: true}
2) {actionsLoading: true, error: null, initialState: true}
3) {actionsLoading: true, address: {<complete object>...}, error: null, initialState: true}
4) {actionsLoading: true, address: {<complete object>...}, error: null, initialState: true}

I'm not really sure I get the thing about the loading state. Many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Ok, so this makes more sense to me. The redux toolkit is unfamiliar to me, but it's trying to reduce boilerplate. So we need to figure out how to handle the loading state with redux toolkit. The issue above is that actionsLoading doesn't get set back to `false` when it is done.

Comment: Oops. My mistake her. The actionsLoading actually does get back to `false` in both step 3 and 4.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well in my message above I setup our own loading state, but since you already have it with `actionsLoading` you just need to do the last part which is to not render if the data is null or we are loading. If you initialize actionsLoading to `true` then you can just checking loading and only render the address when its not loading. Make sense?

Comment: Hi there, just wanted to provide an update, as it seems like I found a solution. I took advantage of your suggestion to remove the Object.values() thing. However, I mainly changed the structure of my `addressActions.js` and `addressSlice.js` (which should probably be renamed now) files and took a simpler approach that I found elsewhere.  The changes are a bit too long to post here.

Comment: Thanks for the update, glad that you were able to sort it out. Hopefully I had some impact on you understanding the loading state requirements for API fetching.